# Ajax MVC partialView

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, razor

I've run into a problem with rendering a partialView in my web application.
What I'm trying to do is using a @Ajax.ActionLink() to fill a div when a **button/link is pressed** with the content of another view. The issue I'm meeting is that instead of filling the div it reloads the content into a new page, rather than filling the div. All the other answers I've looked up says the same and my syntax is pretty much the same. Is there something in between I've missed or that I should've know before I started attempting this?

Here's my actionlink

```
<body>
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar">Hei</span>
                <span class="icon-bar">På</span>
                <span class="icon-bar">Deg</span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div>
            @Ajax.ActionLink("Last inn partial view", "_LoadView", new AjaxOptions { InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace, HttpMethod = "get", UpdateTargetId="result"})
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="container body-content">
    @RenderBody()
    <hr />
    <footer>
        <p>&copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - My ASP.NET Application</p>
    </footer>
</div>
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/ajax");
```

Here's the div I want to fill in

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="content background">
        <div id="result">Her står det masse text</div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Here's the controller

```
 [HttpGet]
    public PartialViewResult _LoadView()
    {
        return PartialView();
    }
```

EDIT:

Forgot to mention that I've got a BundleConfig.cs set up and I've made sure it works as I'm rendering my css through it, though this is the first script I've tried.

```
        public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include("~/scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include("~/scripts/jquery.validate*"));
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include("~/scripts/modernizr-*"));
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include("~/scripts/bootstrap.js"));
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/ajax").Include("~/scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js", "~/scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js"));
        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include("~/Content/bootstrap.css", "~/Content/bootstrap-theme.css", "~/Content/bankstyle.css"));
    }
}
```

EDIT: added some text to the question to make it clearer, bolded it out to make it clear. I'm very much open to alternative solutions

EDIT: Realized what I was really looking for was the modal framework in bootstrap. Thanks for the suggestions

Comment: do you install jquery unobtrusive ?

Comment: `Ajax.ActionLink` generates a standard anchor link and a bit of JavaScript to hijack it to handle the request via AJAX rather than the default behavior of changing the view. If the default behavior is occurring, that means that that JavaScript is not being run, which indicates there's some sort of error on the page.

Comment: Nice description, @ChrisPratt

Comment: Considered using @html.Action? would call an action when the page loads and return a view

Comment: @Ra3IDeN He clearly doesn't want a link, he wants a partial view loading within an element in his view using html helpers.

Comment: Please copy code directly into the question, rather than use screenshots.  For some people, those screenshots are *extremely* difficult to see.

Comment: @Ryan Searle html.action is not a link. It loads the content directly by calling an action. To every problem there are numerous soloutions and I provided an alternative one.

Comment: @Ra3IDeN My mistake, I read your comment as `@Url.Action()`

Comment: to be fair you're both right., what I want is both a link and a partial view. I want to a pop-up when a user clicks log in. I could be approaching it all wrong using a partial view.

Comment: @Iltharion if I uderstand you correctly you wish to click on a link and then you want a popup to appear for a login form? I will update my answer during the day if you can come back to me and notify me if my assumption is correct. In the mean while consider reading up on "bootstrap modal".

Answer (score 1):

Please run this in console:

```
PM> Install-Package Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax -Version 3.2.2
```

For install please follow next steps: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax/

Then you must use script file which is located in Scripts folder

Answer (score 0):

Install the Unobtrusive js file:

Run in nuget: `Install-Package Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Ajax`

Add this to your view:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.min.js")
```

Comment: thanks, forgot to mention that I've got a bundleconfig loading my scripts

Answer (score 0):

This is not the the answer to the original question but an alternative soloution:

using [html.action](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee728618(v=vs.118).aspx)

```
<div id="contentContainer">
   @Html.Action("Action", "Controller")
</div>
```

This will call an action and render the view that you return from the action.

Answer (score 0):

Found out what I was really looking for was the modal framework in bootstrap. Fixed my issues in 5 minutes.